# regex pattern for various number groups

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am parsing a list of code numbers, they have a pattern of `12345.1211`. They are `space` delimited.
They sometimes will have a space followed by one - three addition number patterns like:
`1221.121 11 111.111111 874.95 1211`

I have a regex: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` **

It finds a decimated number like `12345.1211` as . I encapsulate the regex with `(` & `)` and use `\1\n` to break each code with a newline.

I am using Notepad++ with find an replace. But the regex falls short with the space-included numbers.
The extra numbers endup on the same line as the next pattern.

Example:

```
1221.121 11 111.111111  874.95 1211 456.155
```

I got:

```
1221.121
11 111.111111
874.95
1211 456.155
```

Is there anything I can do to optionally include the extra numbers separated by a space?

Comment: The list is space delimited, yet you have codes that include spaces?

Comment: If it is space delimited but the pattern needs to sometimes (but only sometimes) include spaces, then you will need to rigorously define when a space needs to be included and when it does not. If the definition is precise and accurate enough, then you could probably write a regex, but without that definition it isn't really possible to write one that would be 100% correct.

Comment: Also posting the exact regex that you are currently using will help us understand better what you are trying to do and where a fix might need to go.

Comment: The regex that I am using is listed, and highlighted. The list is space delimited, because it was copied from a webpage.  In my example data sets, a valid CODE number shouldn't have a space in it.  However my employer has made exceptions to that rule. Anytime there is a CODE number with a space, it typically has one space followed by two numbers.  But there have been examples where it trailed with one or three digits. But those are even rarer.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer my self. If it run the regex: ([0-9]+) , which leads with a space, and trails with a space will only find a number pattern that has a space in front and behind it. Since valid Code Numbers will have a decimal, this will only find, what would be the extra digits. I wrapped it in parens, and use a back reference, lead it with an underscore, and trail it with a space. '_\1 ' So it will attach the extra digits to the parent, and delimit the whole string with a space.  I then add and undersore to my regex pattern like so. "([0-9]+\.[0-9_]+) "

Answer (score 0):

On your test data this regex matches all the numbers perfectly for me;

`[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\K\h+`
- Replace with: `\n`         or `\r\n` for windows linebreak
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
\d+             # 1 or more digits
(?:             # start non capture group
    \.          # a dot
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
)?              # end group, optional
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]